# Subviews not recognized in UIViewController connected to xib file

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib, subview

I have a UIViewController swift file that's connected to xib file (I clicked create xib when I created the viewController). Now, it doesn't recognize any subview in the main view.

When I write "po self.view.subviews" while debugging. It returns 0. all subViews (a tableView and textView and label) = nil. I even created a new project and still get the same error.
Im at loss here.

Here's my code from the AboutUsViewController swift file:

import UIKit

import Foundation

class AboutUsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! 

@IBOutlet weak var contactsTableView: UITableView!

let items = ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let NibName = UINib(nibName: "ContactUsTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    contactsTableView.register(NibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContactUsTableViewCell")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.®
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.item == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactUsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactUsTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = "HIII"
        return cell

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactUsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactUsTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (indexPath.item == 0) {
        return 200
    } else {
        return 86
    }
}
```

}

[my swift file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLSWw.png)

[my xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGKv.png)

Comment: Can you share a demo

Comment: can you check. the file owner for xib is set correctly as AboutUsViewController

Comment: @ManuRaphy it was set properly. The issue was fixed when I followed Sh_Khan's answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to load the vc like this

```
let vc = AboutUsViewController(nibName: "AboutUsViewController", bundle: nil)
self.window?.rootViewController = vc
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I've been trying to fix this for two hours. Do you know why my old code wasn't working? under func applications in the app delegate, I had: if self.window == nil {
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.rootViewController = AboutUsViewController()
            window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

Comment: now I have: 
let viewController = AboutUsViewController(nibName: "AboutUsViewController", bundle: nil)
        if self.window == nil {
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.rootViewController = viewController
            window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }